# Prove If $\alpha$ is a non zero limit ordinal then ${\omega}^{\alpha}$ is a limit ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

My attempt so far is that if ${\omega}^{\alpha}$ = sup(${{\omega}^{\alpha}}$)

then ${\omega}^{\alpha}$ is a limit ordinal.

For ${\omega}^2$ case: ${\omega}^2$= $\omega$ $\cdot$ $\omega$ = sup{${\omega}{\cdot}n {\mid}n<{\omega}$}

And then, for ${\beta} + 1 $ $\leq$ ${\omega}^2$

which shows that the above is a limit ordinal.

But I am having trouble for showing ${\omega}^{\alpha}$ case.

How should I proceed from here?

I am very new to this set theory area, and stuck on this question for hours, thanks for any help or guidance for this problem win advance.

Comment: Isn't $\omega^\alpha$ always a limit ordinal?

Comment: How about writing down the definition of $\omega^\alpha$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Isn't that what we're (partially) proving here?

Comment: @LordShark not if $\alpha=0$ :)

Comment: @Arthur I think the point is just that the statement is too weak. But really it’s understandable here since it doesn’t take any actual work to show it for a limit, just definition chasing, whereas the nonzero successor case requires an argument (unless I’m missing something).

Comment: Maybe what you really need to show something stronger, such as: if $\alpha$ is a nonzero limit ordinal, then $\omega^\alpha$ is a limit of limit ordinals.

Comment: Well, $\omega^\alpha$ for non-zero, limit $\alpha$ can be defined as $\sup\{\omega ^ \beta | \beta \in \alpha\}$ so you can reduce the problem to prove that $\{\omega^\beta | \beta \in \alpha\}$ is an infinite set right?